# Adjusting nested dictionary depending on provided key values

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

I would like to create the following dictionary based on various parameters given by `params`. Now I do not want to add keys which provide no value. So for instance if `params['ean']` is blank or does not exist I want to exclude the entire line `"EAN": params['ean']`. Any suggestions are highly welcome.

```
myitem = {
"Item": {
     "Title": params['title'],
     "Description": "Some Text",
     "PrimaryCategory": {"CategoryID": params['category_id']},
     "ISBN": params['isbn'],
     "EAN": params['ean']
}
}
```

Please note that that params will not have the same keys like myitem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you can change the way you create the dict** just user dict comprehension:

```
myitem = {k: v for k, v in params.items() if v}
```

If you already have the dict in first place and you **can't change the initialization** of it, you can delete the empty values like that:

```
for k, v in myitems.items():
    if not v:
        del myitems[k]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think i understand the question perfectly but how about something like that:

```
myitem = {}
myitem['Item'] = {"Description": "Some Text"}
for keys in ['title', 'category_id', 'isbn', 'ean']:
    if params[keys]:
        myitem['Item'].append({keys.upper(): params[keys]})
```

which produces:

```
myitem = {"Item": {"TITLE": params['title'],
                   "Description": "Some Text",
                   "CATEGORY_ID": params['category_id'],
                   "ISBN": params['isbn'],
                   "EAN": params['ean']
                   }
          }
```

Notice that at this stage the category id does not match your specifications exactly but that can be easily *fetched* using the following:

```
myitem["item"].append({"PrimaryCategory": myitem["item"].pop(["CategoryID"])})
```

which takes advantage of the `pop`'s return so it removes and re-adds the `"CATEGORY_ID": params['category_id']` key value pair leaving you with the desired result (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code does what you are looking for.

```
d = {}

def addItem(name, description, params):
    d[name] = {}
    if 'title' in params:
        d[name]['Title'] = params['title']
    if 'category_id' in params:
        d[name]['PrimaryCategory'] = {"CategoryID" : params['category_id']}
    if 'isbn' in params:
        d[name]['ISBN'] = params['isbn']
    if 'ean' in params:
        d[name]['EAN'] = params['ean']
    d[name]['Description'] = description

params1 = {'title' : 'Boh'}
addItem('item1', 'item1 description', params1)
params2 = {'title' : 'Boh 2', 'isbn' : '12345'}
addItem('item2', 'item2 description', params2)
print d
```